# What is best practice to interact with subprocesses in python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm building an apllication which is intended to do a bulk-job processing data within another software. To control the other software automatically I'm using **pyautoit**, and everything works fine, except for application errors, caused from the external software, which occur from time to time.

To handle those cases, I built a watchdog:

- It starts the script with the bulk job within a subprocess

  ```
   process = subprocess.Popen(['python', job_script, src_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  ```
- It listens to the system event using **winevt.EventLog** module

  ```
   EventLog.Subscribe('System', 'Event/System[Level<=2]', handle_event)
  ```
- In case of an error occurs, it shuts down everything and re-starts the script again.

Ok, if an system error event occurs, this event should get handled in a way, that the supprocess gets notified. This notification should then lead to the following action within the subprocess:

> Within the subprocess there's an object controlling everything and continuously collecting
> generated data. In order to not having to start the whole job from the beginnig, after re-starting the script, this object has to be dumped using pickle (which isn't the problem here!)

Listening to the system event from inside the subprocess didn't work. It results in a continuous loop, when calling subprocess.Popen().

So, my question is how I can either subscribe for system events from inside a childproces, or communicate between the parent and childprocess - means, sending a message like "hey, an errorocurred",  listening within the subprocess and then creating the dump?

I'm really sorry not being allowed to post any code in this case. But I hope (and actually think), that my description should be understandable. My question is just about what module to use to accomplish this in the best way?

Would be really happy, if somebody could point me into the right direction...

Br,
Mic

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best answer may lie here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin

These attributes should allow for proper communication between the different processes fairly easily, and without any other dependancies.

Note that Popen.communicate() may suit better if other processes may cause issues.

EDIT to add example scripts:

main.py

```
from subprocess import *
import sys

def check_output(p):
    out = p.stdout.readline()
    return out

def send_data(p, data):
    p.stdin.write(bytes(f'{data}\r\n', 'utf8'))  # auto newline
    p.stdin.flush()

def initiate(p):
    #p.stdin.write(bytes('init\r\n', 'utf8'))  # function to send first communication
    #p.stdin.flush()
    send_data(p, 'init')
    return check_output(p)

def test(p, data):
    send_data(p, data)
    return check_output(p)

def main()
    exe_name = 'Doc2.py'
    p = Popen([sys.executable, exe_name], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE)
    
    print(initiate(p))
    print(test(p, 'test'))
    print(test(p, 'test2'))  # testing responses
    print(test(p, 'test3'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Doc2.py

```
import sys, time, random

def recv_data():
    return sys.stdin.readline()

def send_data(data):
    print(data)

while 1:
    d = recv_data()
    #print(f'd: {d}')
    if d.strip() == 'test':
        send_data('return')
    elif d.strip() == 'init':
        send_data('Acknowledge')
    else:
        send_data('Failed')
```

This is the best method I could come up with for cross-process communication. Also make sure all requests and responses don't contain newlines, or the code will break.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good)) But how can I get the message which is sent via stdin within the subprocess? Means, in the script which is running within that process? How to implement this?

Comment: I believe you should use sys.stdin to read from the stream. I will test a program and give some example code in a bit.